# python overriding a classmethod with an instance method

Tags: python, inheritance

I came across a bug in my code where an overriding method was hidden because I'd forgotten the `@classmethod` decorator. I was wandering if it's possible to force the other way (noted it's probably bad design) but something like:

```
 class Super:

   @classmethod
   def do_something(cls):
     ...

class Child:
  def do_something(self):
    ...

obj = Child()
obj.do_something() #calls the child
Child.do_something() #calls the Super method
```

EDIT: No specific case at the moment but I was wandering if it could hypothetically be done.

Comment: This seems like terrible design. What is your use case? Maybe we can provide something better.

Comment: I suggest you write a simple Python program to try it out.  Nothing helps me understand the behavior of a language or library better than testing.

Comment: You might like to start using "new" style classes.

Comment: @japreiss Yes I did that and it didn't override. I was wandering if there was a way to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a pure hypothetically application, this could be one way:

```
class Super:
   @classmethod
   def do_something(cls):
     print('Super doing something')

class Child(Super):
    def __init__(self):
        self.do_something = lambda: print('Child Doing Something')
```

Example:

```
>>> obj = Child()
>>> obj.do_something()
Child Doing Something
>>> Child.do_something()
Super doing something
>>> obj.do_something()
Child Doing Something
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override the class method with another class method that takes an instance of that class as an argument. In that method, do what you need to do to it and then return it. That way you could do

```
instance = Child.do_something(instance)
```

However, I do not recommend doing that whatsoever.